# SQL - Combining 3 Tables Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I apologize as I am new to SQL and stackoverflow. Also, I did not design the database and it can't be currently changed. 
I have the following tables:

**Clients** (ClientId , Client_Name)

**Client_Purchases** ( Purchase_id, ClientID, Credits, Credits_logged)

**Service_Log** (LogId, Purchase_id, log_date)

I would like to display all clients who have 0 credits, arranged by the most recent log_date.
To do this, I want to first take the sum(Credits - Credits_logged) and if they equal 0, then I know the client has no credits left (remember client can have multiple Client_Purchases). Then to arrange by the most recent log_date which is where I seem to be running into issues.

If I do the following:

```
SELECT  a.ClientId, a.Client_Name, (max(c.log_date))
FROM `Client_Purchases` AS a, Clients AS b, Service_Log AS c
WHERE b.ClientId=a.ClientId AND a.Purchase_id = c.Purchase_id
GROUP BY a.ClientId
HAVING sum(a.Credits-a.Credits_logged) = 0
ORDER BY (max(c.log_date)) DESC
```

It is almost right except it is still showing clients who since might have made purchases. I think the issue lies somewhere connecting the table via Purchase_id. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I didn't understand expected output from what I understand I didn't see problem. Can you please give a sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this:-

```
 SELECT a.ClientId, a.Client_Name, (max(c.log_date)) 
 FROM Client_Purchases AS a, Clients AS b, Service_Log AS c
 WHERE b.clientid=a.clientid       //stuid is not a column in your table as mentioned
 AND a.Purchase_id = c.Purchase_id 
 GROUP BY a.ClientId 
 HAVING sum(a.Credits-a.Credits_logged) = 0 
 ORDER BY (max(c.log_date)) 
 DESC
```

Comment: Sorry...yes. this is the original one that I tried. I changed some of the names to make it make more sense and forgot to change stuid to clientid

Comment: Just to clarify, it does not seem to be filtering out clients whos sum of all credits from client purchases = 0.

Comment: and to clarify more...a client should completely disappear from this list if they make a new purchase...